# How to add data-aos-delay in .map function

Tags: next.js, bots

I want to add data-aos-delay like first value = 50, second =100 third=150, fouth=50 and so on...

how do i do it in .map function

using next-js

.map function code is below:

```
    {blogs.slice(0).map((item) => {
                return <Link key={item.slug.current} href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                  <article className="ip oo ik" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay={`${delay}`}>
                    <header>
                      <a href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                        <span className="ic re" href="blog-post.html">
                          <figure className="tq ig fe o_ oq">
                            <Image className="tj tz su ik an o lz ci cl" src={builder.image(item.mainImage).width().url()} layout='fill' sizes="50vw" priority='true' quality={60} alt={item.Alt} />
                          </figure>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                   <h3 className="h3 ra"> <span className="c_ lz cr cf text-hover text-2xl " href="blog-post.html"><a href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>{item.title}</a></span> </h3>

                    </header>
                    <a href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                      <p className="fm li sz hover:text-black dark:hover:text-white">{item.metadesc}</p>
                    </a>
                    <footer className="ip ol rv"> <span>
                      {/* <Image className="oj sq rl" src="/" width="40" height="40" alt="Author 01" /> */}
                    </span>
                      <div className="fk"> <span className="lr c_ lz cr cf text-hover">{item.Name}</span> <span className="lc"> - </span> <span className="lf">{item.publishedAt}</span> </div>
                    </footer>

                  </article>

                </Link>
              })}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `const delay = (index % 3 + 1) * 50`?

Comment: problem has been solved... Thank you